# Don't Care in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to tell Prolog that an element in a list can be any value?
I tried using `_` but  it didn't work.
I'm trying to compare two lists of zeros and ones but in some places I don't care about the value, for example: I want `[1,1,1] == [1,1,_]` to return `true` where `_` is the element I don't care about it's value

Comment: Although `_` is "don't care" it's still a variable. So with the strict equality `==/2` the terms `1` and `_` don't match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
[1,1,1] = [1,1,_]
```

`==/2` tests for equivalence, which is stronger than `=/2` (which instantiates).

Answer (score 0):

Non-unifying alternative:

```
forall(nth1(X, [1,1,1], Val), nth1(X, [1,1,_], Val)).
```

Some sample input and output to show where lies the difference:

```
compare_lists(List1, List2) :-
     forall(nth1(Index, List1, Value), nth1(Index, List2, Value)).

test_compare(CompPred, ComparedList) :-
    call(CompPred, ComparedList, [1,1,_]).

?- test_compare(=, [X,1,1]), print(X).
1
X = 1.

?- test_compare(=@=, [X,1,1]), print(X).
false.

?- test_compare(==, [X,1,1]), print(X).
false.

?- test_compare(compare_lists, [X,1,1]), print(X).
_G648
true.
```